# Adding products to cart programmatically, sets item's price to zero. First time Only

Tags: magento2, addtocart, quote

Certain products I have in my store have an attribute called setup_fee_sku.

If the product has this attribute I grab the value (which is a sku)  load it, and add it to the cart programatically.

But the price is always set to 0 the first time its added, no matter what kind of sku it is.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/WpXD8GH]

After the item is in the cart for the first time, any other time it is added it contains the correct price.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/5TqPfpL]

I am doing my logic in an observer for event  **checkout_cart_add_product_complete**

This is what my codes looks like

```
$setupSku = $product->getSetupFeeSku();
//Add setup fee to cart if it exists
if($setupSku != null){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $setupProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->get($setupSku);
    $formKey = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey')->getFormKey();

    $params = array(
        'formKey' => $formKey,
        'product' => $setupProduct->getId(),
        'qty' => 100
    );

    $this->cart->addProduct($setupProduct, $params);
    $this->cart->save();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event.

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="sr_checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="SR\MagentoCommunity\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Observer/CheckoutCartProductAddAfter.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class CheckoutCartProductAddAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * CheckoutCartProductAddAfter constructor.
     *
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        try {
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
            $setupSku = $product->getSetupFeeSku();
            if ($setupSku) {
                $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
                $quote = $quoteItem->getQuote();
                $product = $this->productRepository->get($setupSku);
                $requestInfo = [
                    'product' => $product->getId(),
                    'qty' => 1
                ];
                $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($requestInfo);
                $quote->addProduct($product, $request);
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran What's wrong with this answer? Check my answer for avoiding 0 for first time.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you @SohelRana

Comment: same issue with helper data